# Getting distance

Tags: discrete-mathematics

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eH87b.png)

Pleases take a look at the picture.
AC = a, AB = b, I just made a distance from A point as k(CD = k).

At that time how to get the lengths of DF(d) and BF(c)?

Comment: not clear what values are given, you need the length of DF in terms of $a,b,k$?

Comment: @Lee, Thanks for the comment, I'd like to get BF and DF from $a, b, k$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Let $CE=e$, $EB=f$, $ED=d_1$, $FE=d_2$.

Then $\triangle ABC\sim\triangle CDE$, thus $\frac{CA}{CE}=\frac{AB}{CD}$, i.e. $e=\frac{ak}{b}$.

From $\triangle CDE$ we get $d_1=\sqrt{e^2+k^2}$.

From $\triangle EFB\sim\triangle ECD$, we get $d_2=\frac{ce}{k}$.

From $\triangle ABC\sim\triangle FBE$, we get $\frac{a}{d_2}=\frac{e+f}{f}=\frac{e+\sqrt{d_2^2+c^2}}{\sqrt{d_2^2+c^2}}$, insert $d_2=\frac{ce}{k}$, then

\begin{equation}
c=\frac{\frac{ak}{e}\sqrt{\frac{e^2}{k^2}+1}-e}{\sqrt{\frac{e^2}{k^2}+1}}.
\end{equation}

Now you can calculate $d=d_1+d_2$ and $c$ in terms of $a,b,k$ by inserting $e=\frac{ak}{b}$.

Comment: what do you mean $k$ is negative? the distance here cannot be negative, right?

Comment: Oh sorry, when I draw the vertical line(CD) in reverse, I can get it by $d = d2-d1$. right?

Comment: Thanks. But I'm not able to increase the vote number. I'm not sure what the issue is.that button is not working.